# PyCharm, how to change the font of the Quick Documentation window

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2016.1 on windows 7 with its locale set to PRC-Chinese.

In the Quick Documentation window, the first-2-lines look odd (some Chinese-SimSun font?). However, the last line is fine.

How can I change the font of those odd lines?
(hacking into some CSS in some jar?)

[image: ugly-quick-doc-window]

I've already changed the editor font to Consolas (its default value was also the odd SimSun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In idea, I add code below into idea64.exe.vmoptions, this changes SimSun to Courier New when display code in documentation, much better at least, hope it works for you.

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.region=US
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```